# Python multiprocessing doesn't nest subprocess?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have code that looks something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import logging

m = [0,1,2,3]
iter_state = 0

class gener(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.c = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        print "n"
        time.sleep(3)
        ret = self.m[self.c]
        self.c += 1
        return ret 

tt  = gener(m)

itst = multiprocessing.Array('i', 3)

def gen(t):
    itst[t] = t

multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)    

tm = time.time()

job1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt.next(),))
job2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt.next(),))
job3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt.next(),))


job1.start()
job2.start()
job3.start()
job3.join()

for i in itst: 
    print i

tm = time.time() - tm
print tm
```

With the following output:

### OUT:

```
n
n
n
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-1] process shutting down
[DEBUG/Process-1] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Process-1] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/Process-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/Process-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-2] process shutting down
[DEBUG/Process-2] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Process-2] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/Process-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/Process-3] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-3] process shutting down
[DEBUG/Process-3] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Process-3] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/Process-3] process exiting with exitcode 0
0
1
2
9.01742887497
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
```

So we can see that the parallelization actually doesn't work at all.

However, when the `time.sleep()` call is placed inside of the `gen()` function, we see this:

```
import multiprocessing
import logging

m = [0,1,2,3]
iter_state = 0

class gener(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.c = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        print "n"
        ret = self.m[self.c]
        self.c += 1
        return ret 

tt  = gener(m)

itst = multiprocessing.Array('i', 3)

def gen(t):
    time.sleep(3)
    itst[t] = t

multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)    

tm = time.time()

job1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt.next(),))
job2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt.next(),))
job3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt.next(),))


job1.start()
job2.start()
job3.start()
job3.join()

for i in itst: 
    print i

tm = time.time() - tm
print tm
```

### OUT:

```
n
n
n
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-3] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-1] process shutting down
[DEBUG/Process-1] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Process-1] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/Process-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/Process-3] process shutting down
[DEBUG/Process-3] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Process-3] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/Process-3] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/Process-2] process shutting down
[DEBUG/Process-2] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Process-2] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/Process-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
0
1
2
3.01985812187
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
```

Now we can see that parallelization works fine!

**BUT unfortunately only for the `gen()` function.**

**My question:**

How can we achieve to the parallelization work inside of the `next()` method too?

Comment: Your code is still not parallel when time.sleep() is moved to inside gen. Add k = [i for i in range(10000000)] to the next function to see what I mean

Comment: kezzos: Sure not! That is why I asked my question here. It seems gen() the only function is parallel here. What I'd like to obtain that the next() function be parallel too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do it by only actually calling `next()` inside of `gen`. Right now, you're calling `tt.next()` in the parent process, and passing the return value to the child. Instead, you should just pass the entire `tt.next` method to the child. But note that by doing that, you need to make `gener.c` a process-shared variable, and use a process-safe lock to protect the section of code where you increment it.

```
import multiprocessing
import logging
import time

class gener(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = m
        self.c = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        print "n"
        time.sleep(3)
        with self.c.get_lock():
            ret = self.m[self.c.value]
            self.c.value += 1
        return ret 

def gen(func):
    t = func()
    itst[t] = t

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = [0,1,2,3]
    iter_state = 0

    tt  = gener(m)
    itst = multiprocessing.Array('i', 3)
    multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)    

    tm = time.time()

    jobs = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=gen, args=(tt.next,)) for _ in range(3)]
    for j in jobs:
        j.start()
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    for i in itst: 
        print i

    tm = time.time() - tm
    print tm
```

Output:

```
[INFO/Process-3] child process calling self.run()
n
[INFO/Process-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/Process-2] child process calling self.run()
n
n
[INFO/Process-2] process shutting down
[INFO/Process-3] process shutting down
[INFO/Process-1] process shutting down
[DEBUG/Process-1] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Process-1] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[DEBUG/Process-3] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Process-3] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[DEBUG/Process-2] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/Process-2] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
[INFO/Process-2] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/Process-1] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/Process-3] process exiting with exitcode 0
0
1
2
3.02282786369
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running all "atexit" finalizers with priority >= 0
[DEBUG/MainProcess] running the remaining "atexit" finalizers
```

Comment: dano: Thank you vary much! I am extremely happy, that this problem got solved with your help. I worked on it 3-4 days and built it up from the bases. The literature is so gappy in this theme. So thank you once again. PS.: it's a bit mistifying what you done with c.get_lock, though I understand what did you do, but I am interested in the details. Could you please give me some link to study it?

Comment: @GyörgySolymosi `multiprocessing.Value` objects have a built-in recursive lock that can be used to synchronize access to them, which you access by calling `get_lock()` on the object. It's explained in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value).

Comment: btw I'm newbie here, why can't I insert mini formatting into my comments? Or I can and only I can't see it? e.g. If I use @dano at the start of my comment, it always disappears somehow, after I press the Save Edits button I:)

Comment: @GyörgySolymosi No problem. That picture was taken in [The Hollywood Brown Derby](https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/dining/hollywood-studios/hollywood-brown-derby/). (Though I do enjoy pubs, too :) You should be able to use mini-Markdown formatting in your comments. If you click the "help" text that appears under the "Add Comment" button, you'll see an explanation of what syntax is used to do that.

Comment: Nice place, and thank you once again, although @dano disappeared again. (from the start of my comment)

Comment: @GyörgySolymosi It disappears because it's not actually required in this case - I get a notification whenever someone comments on my answer, so it's not required for that, and since we're the only two people who have commented on this answer, there's no ambiguity about who you're directing the comment to. If someone else had commented, or if we were commenting on a question or an answer that didn't belong to me, it wouldn't be removed.